# Eclipse : Maven search dependencies doesn't work (and there is no "Full Index Enable" option)

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

The dependencies search box never offers any dependencies, and when I try to follow the instructions found online, they always say the same 2 things, which among other, don't work

I tried these (among many other things, other computers, other OS, other networks etc, other Eclipse versions, etc)

1. "Go to Window -> Prefrences -> Maven and check "Download repository index updates on start". Restart Eclipse and then look at the progress view. An index file should be downloading."- This isn't changing anything
2. "You also need to rebuild your Maven repository index in 'maven repository view'.
   In this view , open 'Global Repositories', right-click 'central', check 'Full Index Enable', and then, click 'Rebuild Index' in the same menu."- when i right click on central, there is no Full Index Enable option, just "copy URL" and "collapse"

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2022-12 (4.26.0)

Comment: Did you solve? I am facing the same issue, the 'right-click and update' solution is not applicable, because that option is not present in the menu.